# Optimize finding GCD of all pairs of divisors

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge

I've come up with a solution for [Euler Problem 530](https://projecteuler.net/problem=530), but my code runs too slowly to actually get the answer (solving for 10^15). What can I do to optimize it to run faster?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        double bigtotal = 0;
        double n = double.Parse(num);
        Dictionary<double, List<double>> divisorDict = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
        Dictionary<double, double> gcdSums = new Dictionary<double, double>();
        for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            List<double> divisors = getDivisors(i);
            divisorDict[i] = divisors;
            double total = 0;
            foreach (double d in divisors) {
                double gcd;
                if (gcdSums.ContainsKey(d)) {
                    gcd = gcdSums[d];
                } else {
                    List<double> divA = divisorDict[d];
                    List<double> divB = divisorDict[i / d];
                    gcd = GCD(divA, divB);
                    gcdSums[d] = gcd;
                }
                total += gcd;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("The total is " + total);
            bigtotal += total;
            if (i % 1000 == 0) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
        }
        Console.Write("The big total is" + bigtotal + "\n");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static double GCD(List<double> divA, List<double> divB) {
        foreach (double i in divA) {
            foreach (double j in divB) {
                if (i == j) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        return 0;
    }

    static List<double> getDivisors(double a) {
        List<double> divisors = new List<double>();
        for (double i = 1; i <= a/2; i++) {
            if ((a / i) % 1 == 0) {
                divisors.Add(i);
            }
        }
        divisors.Add(a);
        divisors.Reverse();
        return divisors;
    }
```

Comment: Always describe *in the question* what your code does, even if you got your inspiration on some other site and also linked that (as you should).

Answer (score 3):

- **Superficial optimization**

  - I don't see the reason for using `double`. \$10^{15}\$ fits in 50 bits, so 64 bit integers would suffice.
  - `GCD` does a linear search over `divB`. Consider binary search instead.
  - A divisor computation loop runs while \$i \le \frac{a}{2}\$ (`i <= a/2`). It should only run while \$i^2 \le a\$ (`i*i <= a`).
- **Real optimization**

  The problem asks to compute \$ F(k)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^k \, \sum\limits_{d|n}\, \text{gcd}(d,\frac n d)\$

  Swapping the order of summation (that is, outer sum is over divisors `d`, inner sum is over integers divisible by this divisors, that is, `n*d`) results in \$F(k) = \sum\limits_{d=1}^{d^2 <= k} \, \sum\limits_{n=1}^{dn <=k}\, \text{gcd}(d, n)\$.

  Notice that this order runs in \$O(k \log^2k)\$ computations of `gcd` and avoids factorization whatsoever. It does require computation of `gcd` which is not an efficiency burden (expected complexity is logarithmic).

  You may further optimize it by removing repeated `gcd` computations and utilizing symmetry between `n` and `d`.