# Project Euler problem 530 - GCD function is inefficient

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

Here is a description of [Project Euler problem 530](https://projecteuler.net/problem=530):

> Every divisor \$d\$ of a number \$n\$ has a **complementary divisor** \$n/d\$.
>
> Let \$f(n)\$ be the sum of the **greatest common divisor** of \$d\$ and \$n/d\$ over all positive divisors \$d\$ of \$n\$, that is \$\displaystyle f(n)=\sum_{d/n}\gcd\left(d, \frac{n}{d}\right)\$.
>
> Let \$F\$ be the summatory function of \$f\$, that is \$\displaystyle F(k) = \sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n)\$.
>
> You are given that \$F(10)=32\$ and \$F(1000)=12776\$.
>
> Find \$F(10^{15})\$.

Yesterday, I asked a question here: [Project Euler Problem 530: sum of sum of greatest common divisors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114935/project-euler-problem-530-sum-of-sum-of-greatest-common-divisors)

I have improved my solution, which is now as follows:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class problem530 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double start = System.nanoTime();

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
    long target = 100000;

    for (long i = 1; i*i <=  target; i++){
                for(long j = i; i*j <= target; j++) {
                    if (i != j) {
                    result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf((GCD(i, j))*2));
                }
                    else {
                        result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                    }
                }
            }


    System.out.println(result);

    double duration = (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000000;

    System.out.println("Your code took " + duration + " seconds to execute.");

}

public static long GCD (long p, long q) {
    if (p == 0) return q;
    else return GCD (q%p,p);
}
```

This solution uses a simplified version of the summation (it avoids factorisation).

However, the GCD function I'm using is computationally expensive and causes the code to be incapable of finding F(x) for large values of x.

Currently:

- It ran F(10^1) = 32 in 0.0027 seconds.
- It ran F(10^3) = 12766 in 0.0042 seconds.
- It ran F(10^5) = 2907546 in 0.091 seconds.
- It ran F(10^7) = 518387613 in 8.034 seconds.
- It ran F(10^8) = 6563728768 in 97.368 seconds.

Clearly, to find F(10^15) would be practically impossible.

I think the solution might be to memoize the GCD function, or find some way to make it linearly more difficult, as opposed to exponentially, which is now happening.

Suggestions?

EDIT: I am not using the summation from the question. I'm using a simplified version of it.

This was suggested in another post on codereview, and it works, as long as I account for symmetry (the multiply by 2 part of the code), except when it's a perfect square. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I've taken another look at the problem, and I have another refinement. It's not a complete solution, though; I suspect that Project Euler 530 is expecting you to have some number-theoretical insight, rather than just a lot of refinements on top of brute force.

The brute-force solution is indeed something like this (in C++ because I like C++ better than Java):

```
template<typename T>
T f(T n)
{
    T sum = 0;
    const T sqrtn = sqrt(n);
    for (T i = 1; i <= sqrtn; ++i) {
        if (n % i) continue;
        sum += gcd(i, n/i);
        if (i*i != n) sum += gcd(i, n/i);
    }
    return sum;
}

template<typename T>
T F(T k)
{
    T sum = 0;
    for (T i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        sum += f(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

By the way, `gcd` itself is going to be very fast no matter what, as long as you're compiling with optimizations turned on. For my C++ testing, I just used `#define gcd std::__gcd`, which turned out to be just a hair faster than the naive `%`-based algorithm and *much* faster than [a "Binary GCD" algorithm I copied from Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Iterative_version_in_C)

This version performs `F(1e6)` in 7.7 seconds.

---

The answer at [Optimize finding GCD of all pairs of divisors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/optimize-finding-gcd-of-all-pairs-of-divisors) provides a very good algorithmic refinement. It reverses the loops so that you have something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T F(T k)
{
    T sum = 0;
    const T sqrtk = sqrt(k);
    for (T d = 1; d <= sqrtk; ++d) {
        const T k_over_d = k/d;
        sum += d;
        for (T n = d+1; n <= k_over_d; ++n) {
            const T g = gcd(n, d);
            sum += 2*g;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is basically what you've implemented, except that you compute `i*i` `sqrt(n)` times instead of just computing `sqrt(n)` *once*, and so on. In other words, you're deliberately pessimizing your code, which is one reason it's hard to identify the real bottlenecks. When doing Project Euler–type speed challenges, you should always eliminate all the *inessential* inefficiencies that you can, so that if any inefficiencies remain, they'll be *essential* to your algorithm (and hopefully point the way to a better algorithm).

This version performs `F(1e7)` in 4.0 seconds.

---

So, looking at that version, the thing that jumped out at me was that we're computing `gcd(n,d)` in the inner loop... over a lot of values of `n`, like, more than `d` different values of `n`. And `gcd(n,d)` is never *bigger* than `d`. So we're summing up the *same* value of `gcd(n,d)` multiple times (for `n` equal to `n1`, and `n1+d`, and `n1+d+d`, and so on). So, I thought to myself, let's split that inner loop into `d` inner loops and compute `1/d`th as many GCDs!

```
template<typename T>
T F(T k)
{
    T sum = 0;
    const T sqrtk = sqrt(k);
    for (T d = 1; d <= sqrtk; ++d) {
        const T k_over_d = k/d;
        for (T n_mod_d = 0; n_mod_d < d; ++n_mod_d) {
            const T g = gcd(n_mod_d, d);
            for (T n = d + n_mod_d; n <= k_over_d; n += d) {
                sum += 2*g;
            }
        }
        sum -= d;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This version performs `F(1e8)` in 6.5 seconds.

I thought Clang (my C++ compiler of choice) was probably smart enough to optimize that inner-inner loop (the one that just adds `2*g` a known number of times). Indeed, manually optimizing it to

```
            const T g = gcd(n_mod_d, d);
            const T iterations = (k_over_d - n_mod_d) / d;
            sum += 2*g*iterations;
```

didn't produce any further speedup, indicating that the compiler was already doing that optimization for me.

---

We can rearrange some of the obvious commutative operations, e.g. instead of subtracting `d` from `sum` for each `d` from `1` to `sqrtk`, we can just subtract `(sqrtk+1) * sqrtk / 2` once... that kind of thing. That doesn't change the shape of the nested loops, so it doesn't affect the runtime of the code; but it makes the code a bit shorter and removes some of the *inessential inefficiency* so that we can see more clearly the *essential* inefficiency we're still trying to get rid of.

```
template<typename T>
T F(T k)
{
    T sum = 0;
    const T sqrtk = sqrt(k);
    for (T d = 1; d <= sqrtk; ++d) {
        const T k_over_d = k/d;
        for (T i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
            sum += gcd(i, d) * ((k_over_d - i) / d);
        }
    }
    return (2 * sum) - ((sqrtk + 1) * sqrtk / 2);
}
```

Aha! Given that `i < d`, that subexpression `((k_over_d - i) / d)` looks suspicious. It can only ever take on one of two values: either `int(k_over_d / d)` if `i <= k_over_d % d`, or that-minus-1 otherwise. So we hoist *that* multiplication out of the loop, and finally we're back to a couple of loops over gcds.

I got another tiny speedup by using a lookup table for `gcd(x,y)` where `x <= y <= 8192`; that version performed `F(1e8)` in 5.0 seconds.

However, you don't need 10x speedups; you need 10000000x speedups, in order to perform `F(1e15)` in a reasonable amount of time. This implies that there's another algorithmic, number-theoretic, approach that will be the actual solution Project Euler is looking for.

---

You might think that another possible solution would be to split up the work and use multithreading to get the answer in parallel. But even supposing that you have a 16-core CPU at your disposal, that's only a 16x speedup at most. To beat Project Euler, you'll need another 625000x speedup from somewhere... and the only place to get that is algorithmic leaps.

---

You might also think that you could speed up the current algorithm by micro-optimizing `gcd` — by memoizing, or using a lookup table (as I did), or something like that. But notice that with the current algorithm, you'll eventually have to perform `gcd(i,d)` for *each* `d` up to `sqrt(1e15)`, i.e., 31.6 million. Unless your proposed micro-optimization can deal with that many different inputs, it probably won't help.

---

EDITED TO ADD: I realized this morning that there's *yet another* rearrangement of the terms that might help. You could look for the sum
\$\sum_{x,y,g} g \cdot\delta(\text{gcd}(x,y)=1 \text{ and } xyg^2 < k)\$.
There happens to be [a handy O(k) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Next_term) for generating all pairs `(x,y) < k` such that `gcd(x,y)==1`. Unfortunately, O(k) in your case is O(1e15), which is simply too slow. So this doesn't help. What you need is a way to *count* those coprime pairs in O(something small), combined with a way to use that information to compute the sum you're looking for.

(And if we had any eggs, we'd have ham and eggs... if we had any ham.)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public static long GCD (long p, long q) {
>     if (p == 0) return q;
>     else return GCD (q%p,p);
> }
> ```

The iterative version of this is

```
public static long gcd(long a, long b) {
    while ( 0 != b ) {
        long temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp % b;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Note:  the rename of the variable names is purely because the snippet I found was using these names.  Replacing `a` with `p`, `b` with `q`, and `gcd` with `GCD` would be harmless.  Or just stick with these names--also harmless, although you will have to adjust the caller from `GCD` to `gcd` if you do that.

The advice you post also suggests memoizing this.  For the iterative version that would mean checking on each iteration if you've calculated the `gcd` for `a` and `b` previously.  Memoization would actually be simpler to implement on the recursive version, as you could save the result directly before returning.  You might try it both ways (iteration without memoization and recursive with memoization) to see which is faster.  For small values, I'd expect the iterative version to be faster.

I'm not arguing that this will fix your time problems.  I doubt that it will.  This should be faster than your existing method though.